# What consequences arise from holding wort at a high temperaure after fermenation is 100% complete?

Tags: fermentation-temperature, primary-fermentation

I just learned recently via this forum that temperature is most important during primary fermentation, which completes in (roughly) 7 days.

I have fermwraps on my carboys.

What would happen if I set the temperature at above the "manufacturer's recommended optimal temperature range" for three weeks after primary fermentation is complete (meaning, 100% of the wort has been fermented into beer)?

Answer (score 1):

Premature staling?  Ideally, once fermentation is finished, after bright storage, filtering, priming, packaging, &c., beer would stay in a cool, dark location until consumed, with no temperature changes or shocks.

Why do you want to raise the temperature, and to what value? And why 3 weeks?